# How can I send an abstract argument to a web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, xml-serialization, cxf, abstract

I want to send an abstract object as an argument in a webservice method.

These are my classes:
The abstract class:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Male.class, Female.class})

public abstract class Person {
    public String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The extending children:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Male extends Person {

private boolean male;

/**
 * @return the male
 */
public boolean isMale() {
    return male;
}

/**
 * @param male the male to set
 */
public void setMale(boolean male) {
    this.male = male;
}
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Female extends Person{
    private boolean female;

    /**
     * @return the female
     */
    public boolean isFemale() {
        return female;
    }

    /**
     * @param female the female to set
     */
    public void setFemale(boolean female) {
        this.female = female;
    }
}
```

And this is my webservice Interface:

```
@WebService
public interface wsTest {
    @WebMethod
    int getInt();

    @WebMethod
    String getString(String s);

    @WebMethod
    Map<String, String> getMap(Map<String, String> map);

    @WebMethod
    String getMaleStr(Male male);

    @WebMethod
    String getIsMale(@WebParam(name = "param")Person person);
}
```

My problem is that I want to send to the webMethod: getIsMale an object of type Male but the soap message doesn't send it of type Male thus stripping off its "male" member as follows:

The Request when sending:

```
Male male   = new Male();
male.name   = "Avi";
male.setMale(true);
System.out.println("Calling: getIsMale...");
System.out.println("Response is: " + ws.getIsMale(male));
```

Is as follows:

```
[?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?]
[soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"]
  [soap:Body]
    [ns1:getIsMale xmlns:ns1="http://ws.xconnect.com/"]
      [ns1:param]
        [ns2:name xmlns:ns2="http://ws.xconnect.com"]Avi[/ns2:name]
      [/ns1:param]
    [/ns1:getIsMale]
  [/soap:Body]
[/soap:Envelope]
```

Comment: Since a 'Person' can be either male or female, wouldn't it be better to define a 'gender' attribute on Person, which you would set to male or female in the respective subclass' constructor? That way, all Persons have a testable gender?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm surprised JAXB doesn't throw an exception at startup.  You have two types defining the same XmlRootElement.

What you should do is have @XmlType(name="Male"), @XmlType(name="Female"), @XmlType(name="Person) on the classes.   That will setup the TYPE hierarchy correctly.  I wouldn't put an XmlRootElement on any of them.  Let CXF handle that based on the @WebParam's and such.

Comment: I have removed the XmlRootElements and put XmlTypes on them all as per your advice.


1. But the client doesn't send any male/female information, it sends only the name (as there is only "name" information in the "Person" parent).
(I use a tcp proxy to see what the client sends in realtime)


2. The server doesn't get anything useful - only null.

I mean that the method: 
    @Override
     public String getIsMale(Person person) {
      return person.getName();
    }

Throws a NullPointerException.


Do you have any clue which can help solving my two problems?

The

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea.  May need to see a full testcase.  You could  try adding the XmlSeeAlso annotation to the wsTest interface as well.  I'm not sure if that will help or not.  It really sounds like the client doesn't know about the subclasses.